# In what direction does an oscillating charge radiate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

We read that an oscillating charge radiates EMR 
[image]

but the oscillation axis determines a normal plane which is 360° wide. Inthe picture above the charge vibrates on the z-axis, which determines a plane xy.

Can you explain why would the photon decide to propagate in the x-direction and consequently B in the y-direction?

Also, can you confirm if there is only one photon emitted? If so there is an additional problem of photon choosing between x and -x, and probably a problem of conservation of L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

While we think of the EM radiation field, you will find that the oscillating charge radiates in all directions of the plane - and actually off-axis as well! If the angle to the Z axis is $\phi$, then the intensity will be proportional to $\sin\phi$ - this is the classical dipole field.

But intensity just represents the *probability* that you will observe a photon in a particular location. In observing the field from the oscillating charge, you will detect energy in quanta (photons). But it's not emitted as photons... until you observe it, the energy travels in all directions (except, as I mentioned, exactly up the Z axis).